# How to delete docked programs on the 'taskbar' in Linux Mint

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, taskbar

([The taskbar I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJKs3.jpg))

Basically the problem is that the taskbar I'm talking about is the menu to the right of the **Menu** button and after the 3 dots. I've tried dragging it, pressing **delete**, pressing **right-click + delete** and nothing works. My taskbar has **3** terminals, yes 3 terminals, which might be an error but I've only used Windows until now.

The problem started when I accidentally deleted the terminal in what I call the **favourites** part of the taskbar (don't know how I deleted it though). When I tried to bring it back the terminal went to the **non-favourites** part of the taskbar (after the three dots) and now it won't go away. It's actually kind of bad because normally when you were to open a program, a little bar in the taskbar would show up and you could press it and the program would minimize, etc. But now the terminals are there, that bar doesn't show up, and when I go to close a window, I have to open the program again because the bar isn't there and I have no way of opening it again after minimizing it.

Comment: Nvm I got it. **>:(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

meh, body must be at least 30 characters: you entered 8
Well I don't care superuser, so I'm gonna write until you accept it.
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz